# Intl.NumberFormat format cents into correct form

Tags: javascript

Currently, I'm storing price in cents in the database, which means 100 = 1 EUR

I'm using this type of formatting

```
 Intl.NumberFormat("fr-FR", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "EUR",
  }).format(price);
```

The issue is that NumberFormat thinks that those are EUR and format 100 as 100 EUR.

Which way would be the correct one to let NumberFormat know that those are cents. The final result should be shown in EUR ofc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just divide by `100` to get Euro instead of Cent.

```js
const price = 123;

console.log(Intl.NumberFormat("fr-FR", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "EUR",
  }).format(price / 100));
```

Comment: This isn't true for all currencies, FYI: https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal

Comment: Exactly, and I'm desperately looking for an answer about how to handle this correctly